# How to create a time-based BufferingHandler in python?

Tags: python, logging, buffer

I would like to create a time-based `BufferingHandler`. Currently, a `BufferingHandler` is based on a `capacity`, meaning it will flush the records only when this `capacity` is reached as can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L1228):

```py
class BufferingHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.buffer = []

    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        return (len(self.buffer) >= self.capacity)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.buffer.append(record)
        if self.shouldFlush(record):
            self.flush()

    def flush(self):
        self.acquire()
        try:
            self.buffer = []
        finally:
            self.release()
    ...
```

What I tried is:

```py
class TimeBasedBufferingHandler(BufferingHandler):

    def __init__(self, capacity=10, delta=60):
        BufferingHandler.__init__(self)
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.delta = delta  # in seconds (as time.time())

    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        is_full = len(self.buffer) >= self.capacity
        is_old = (record.created - self.buffer[0].created) >= self.delta
        return is_full or is_old
```

The problem in my `TimeBasedBufferingHandler` is that, if no record is received after the last record and `shouldFlush` did not return `True`, some logs will be trapped for a very long time in the buffer, which is not what I want. I still want to release the logs after some time (like `delta`) even if no record has been received to trigger the `emit` function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `flush` yourself manually, from wherever you want, when you want to flush the handler's buffer. You could do this on a timer, for instance, something like:

```
timeout = 60
handler = TimeBasedBufferingHandler(capacity=XXX, delta=timeout)
timer = threading.Timer(timeout, handler.flush)
```

Comment: Thanks, Vinay. Can I add the `timer` as an attribute for my new object? I have tried it, but it seems it sometimes does not trigger..

Comment: Ok, I found out why it couldn't trigger sometimes. I was using a `time.sleep()` somewhere else and it was affecting the `timer` since it was part of the current thread.. Problem solved.

Comment: Where did you put the code? I added this in the constructor but the timer is not working.